# javacript:one check unchecking all other boxes

Tags: javascript

I have a 3 checkbox with none option checkbox at last,I want to make it like when none option is checked then other front two checkboxes are unchecked automatically.But when none is not checked it should able to checked both 1 and 2 boxes.

I tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function uncheck() {
    var allchecked=0;
    var m=document.getElementById("mat");
    var e=document.getElementById("Exam");
    var n=document.getElementById("none");
    if(n.checked) {
      m=allchecked;
      e=allchecked
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

function uncheck()
{
var allchecked=0;
var m=document.getElementById("mat");
var e=document.getElementById("Exam");
var n=document.getElementById("none");

if(n.checked)
 {
   m=allchecked;
   e=allchecked
  }


}
</script

Comment: I try to create functions in this way but still not able to get it

Comment: nowhere in your code do you set the checked state to false...

Comment: I have given a code there..

Comment: I have given var value as 0 so that if last is checked then given var value i could apply there in my if statements

Comment: @ epascarello:I did that in order to make remaining boxes false if last is selected.I hope you have got my logic there but Iam still not able to do it because Iam just beginner in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to set the `checked` property of your checkboxes to `false`

I made [this fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Bj5Rs/) with a wokring solution for you.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mat" onclick="uncheck(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="Exam" onclick="uncheck(this)"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="none" onclick="uncheck(this)"/>
```

Javascript:

```
function uncheck(checkbox) {
  if(checkbox.id == "none" && checkbox.checked){
    document.getElementById("mat").checked = false;
    document.getElementById("Exam").checked = false;
  }else{
    document.getElementById("none").checked = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help you. Feel free to accept the solution with a checkmark to help future help seeking people.